# How to input '^A' ('\u0001' or ascii 001) in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

It's quite easy in vim to input `^A` (Just C^V + 1 + space), but how to do it in notepad++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alt` + `0` `1` works on Windows (type 0 and 1 sequentially with the numpad, making sure that Num Lock is enabled).

If you open `cmd` in Windows, you can also do the following:
`echo ^A > file.txt`

**Note:** `^A` is the representation of `Ctrl` + `A`; please don't type the `^` symbol literally. It will write the symbol in file.txt of the current folder, which you can then open with Notepad++.

Comment: what is `Gr`? `G` + `r`?

Comment: @Sayakiss On some keyboards, one of the `Alt` buttons is called `Alt Gr`. It's the one on the right-hand side. On my computer, both `Alt` keys work for the combinations; other computers may only understand the combinations with one of the two keys. I've removed the "Gr" part, come to think of it.

Comment: `\u0001` is represented by `SOH` in notepad++?

Comment: @Sayakiss Yup, you got it! :) If you look at ASCII tables online, you'll see that `\u0001` is abbreviated by `SOH`.